# Restricting Cell Selection based on section

Tags: swift, model, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView DataSource as such;

```
struct HomeSection {
    var title: String?
    var cellType: [HomeCellType]
    
    init(title: String?, cellType: [HomeCellType]) {
        self.title = title
        self.cellType = cellType
    }
}

struct HomeModel {
    static let model = [
        HomeSection(title: "Stock", cellType: [.inStock(text: "Show In-Stock only")]),
        HomeSection(title: "Product", cellType: [.walls(text: "Walls"), .floors(text: "Floors"), .fabrics(text: "Fabrics")]),
        HomeSection(title: "Similarity", cellType: [.similarity]),
        HomeSection(title: "Upload", cellType: [.camera, .photo])
    ]
}
```

I would like to restrict the

```
HomeSection(title: "Product", cellType: [.walls(text: "Walls"), .floors(text: "Floors"), .fabrics(text: "Fabrics")])
```

to be able to select one cell.  I have done the `override var is Selected` method.  However, once I select another cell in another section it deSelects the cell in that section.  How would I handle this in `didSelectItemForIndexPath`?

### Update

I call my dataSource like this;

```
private let dataSource = HomeViewDataSource(sections: HomeModel.model)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch dataSource.sections[indexPath.section].cellType[indexPath.item] {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for restriction, you can use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    if (condition) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

for having multiple selections at once, you can use:

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

for restrict selections optionally:

Inside `shouldSelect` or `didSelect` check if any unwanted cells is already selected with:

```
collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
```

then deselect them if needed with:

```
collectionView.deselectItem(at: <#IndexPath#>, animated: <#Bool#>)
```

Comment: This is a collectionView

Comment: This works with the deselecting issue but I want only 1 cell selected in that section... How can this be implemented?

Comment: You mean only 1 cell per section but multiple cells per collectionView ?

Comment: I have multiple sections and one of the sections has three cells.  I'd like to only have one of those three cells selected at a time.